# How to add a specific key with a specific value in a firebase database with Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a realtive simple Firebase database, in which i have 2 models. A `ListModel` and a `UserModel`. In my Lists, i'm using `push()` method to generate unique ids. Each unique id i want to be added as a key and "true" as it's value under `Users/gmail@gmail,com/Lists`.
When i add the first list, the database looks like this:

[image]

And everything works fine, but when i try to add another one, the database looks like this:
[image]

In `Users/gmail@gmail,com/Lists`, the first one is overwritten by the second insert. How can i add the specific id and the specific value, as a new item as shown below?

[image]

And this is my code:

```
final UserModel um = new UserModel();
um.setUserEmail("gmail@gmail,com");
userDatabaseReference.setValue(um);

ListModel lm = new ListModel();
lm.setListName(listName);
listKeyDatabaseReference = listDatabaseReference.push();
listKey = listKeyDatabaseReference.getKey();
listKeyDatabaseReference.setValue(lm);

listDatabaseReference.child(listKey).child("Users").child("gmail@gmail,com").setValue("true");
userDatabaseReference.child("gmail@gmail,com").child("Lists").child(listKey).setValue("true");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide more code for how you are writing and listening to the data? The single line you've posted is fine for adding the entry, so isn't enough to explain the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: I have just edited my post and added more code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write):

> For basic write operations, you can use `setValue()` to save data to a specified reference, replacing any existing data at that path.

Your problem is here:

```
userDatabaseReference.setValue(um);
```

In this way you are overriding all children in the `userDatabaseReference` path.
It means that the first record in `Users/gmail@gmail,com/Lists` is just deleted when you are adding the second one.

Before using the

```
userDatabaseReference.setValue(um);
```

you can check **if the record exists**.
If doesn't exist use the `setValue` to add the user-model with all its data.
If it exists, just skip this step and add the data in the `lists` path inside the same user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I unserstand now, but how can i solve the problem?

Comment: It depends by your logic but you can simply use serDatabaseReference.child("gmail@gmail,com").child("Lists").child(listKey).setValue("true"); without using the initial setValue.

Comment: If i don't use the initial `setValue`, all the data from the model will not be added into the database. Do you have any other idea? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexM. what data won't be added? Nothing posted in the question seems to rely on this.

Comment: Which other data do you have in the model? I see that you have only the email and in this case you can just use the last line.

Comment: I do have more data in my model, like: userId, userName, profilePhotoUrl.

Comment: @AlexM. In this case just add the user only if it doesn't exist (and you can use setValue). If exists just add the data in the lists path inside the same user.

Comment: Yes, i think this is the only way i can do it. Please edit your answer. Thank you!